# How to tell where an asyncio task is waiting?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have rather complex system running an asynchronous task called "automation". Meanwhile I would like to inspect where the task is currently waiting. Something like a callstack for async-await.

The following example creates such an `automation` task, stepping into `do_something` which in turn calls `sleep`. While this task is running, its stack is printed. I'd wish to see something like "automation → do_something → sleep". But `print_stack` only points to the line `await do_something()` in the top-level coroutine `automation`, but nothing more.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio

async def sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

async def do_something():
    print('...')
    await sleep()

async def automation():
    for _ in range(10):
        await do_something()

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(automation(), name='automation')
    while not task.done():
        task.print_stack()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I thought about using `_scheduled` from `asyncio.BaseEventLoop`, but this seems to be always `[]` in my example. And since my production code runs uvloop I looked into https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop/issues/135,
https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop/issues/163 and
https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop/pull/171, all of which are stale for about 4 years.

Is there something else I could try?

Comment: 1. You are seeing an empty `_scheduled` because the two sleeps are "in sync". I guess (and only guess) that they are processed in one event loop iteration. Change one slightly. 2. Your main question is quite difficult, IMO. The relationship of coroutines is not based on function calls which create stack frames, but similar to a "yield from" pipeline. 3. The only thing that is maybe related I recall is a feature in `trio` (an `asyncio` alternative) mentioned  here: https://vorpus.org/blog/beautiful-tracebacks-in-trio-v070/

Comment: @VPfB You're right: When changing one interval to 0.11 seconds, `asyncio.get_running_loop()._scheduled` contains a TimerHandle. Not sure, if that's of any use...

Answer (score 0):

I found something: When running asyncio with `debug=True` and using a different interval of 0.11s (to avoid both task being "in sync"), we can access `asyncio.get_running_loop()._scheduled`. This contains a list of `asyncio.TimerHandle`. In debug mode each `TimerHandle` has a proper `_source_traceback` containing a list of `traceback.FrameSummary` with information like `filename`, `lineno`, `name` and `line`.

```py
...

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(automation(), name='automation')
    while not task.done():
        for timer_handle in asyncio.get_running_loop()._scheduled:
            for frame_summary in timer_handle._source_traceback:
                print(f'{frame_summary.filename}:{frame_summary.lineno} {frame_summary.name}')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.11)

asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

The output looks something like this:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:600 run_forever
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:1888 _run_once
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py:80 _run
/Users/falko/./test.py:17 automation
/Users/falko/./test.py:12 do_something
/Users/falko/./test.py:7 sleep
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:601 sleep
```

The main drawback for my application is the fact that uvloop doesn't come with the field `_scheduled`. That's why I'm still looking for an alternative approach.